# Printing Keys or Values from a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python

I'm looking to print keys and values from a dictionary in Python.

Here is my code:

```
dict = {'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}
for (a,b) in dict:
    print(b)
```

However, it is only printing 'k1' [0] or [1].

I get a whole syntax error when then trying to do something like this;

```
storelist = {'fruit':'apple','veg':'carrot','dairy':'cheese'}

for (a,b) in storelist:
    print(b)
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? Can i only print a key or value by using

```
storelist.values()
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Do not use `dict` as a variable name. And you get ValueErrors, not syntax errors.

Comment: Use `dict.items()`.

Comment: `help(dict)` to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods

```
dictionary = {'k1':1,'k2':2,'k3':3}

# print keys
for key in dictionary:
  print(key)

# print values
for key in dictionary:
  print(dictionary[key])

# print keys and values
for (key, value) in dictionary.items():
  print(key)
  print(value)
```